# How to control(start, stop) the web server when the process(spring boot) is running?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets

I'm starting a server, but I want to start it when some conditions meet. With spring boot, I don't know how to control when to start the web server, it just starts when the process start.

Answer (score 1):

There has two way to shut down Spring Boot:

1. Shutdown via http request. Please refer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown).
2. Shutdown as Service. Please refer [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service).

Hope those were helpful.

Comment: I mean stop the web server, not all the application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using certain embed server like embed tomcat, which means your application would automatically start a web server when you start your springboot main. You could make a trigger by shell to start the whole application. Moreover, things like jenkins also could handle your problem.

Comment: It is an embed server. But when the application start, some preparation need to be done, then the embed server start. So how?

Comment: can you simply describe what preparation you need?

Comment: Jenkins provides a combination of tasks, set what you need to prepare before your server starts. If jenkins plugins don 't contain those you need, you can use a shell script in some step in a task combination

Comment: In preparation, I need to load some data, but the web server provide api to write these data. So I need to start the server after loading data.

Comment: So, your problem is using these data to determine if start up your webserver? like a switch?

Comment: Yeah. Start the server when data loads finish, more precisely.

Comment: I would suggest divide these two steps into two microservices. First one would be your switch, it determine the status of your main application. After your data loading and logic part, send a shell command like java -jar  "your main application name".jar